# How to generate various diagrams on the same project with different ecores in GMF?

Tags: plugins, ecore

first I would like to apologize for my English.

I'm developing a project in GMF and he has several EMF .ecore in case models. I wonder how do I create all the diagrams in the same project so that you can run them?

Answer (score 0):

I know this questions is old, but maybe other users stumble upon this.
I think what you are looking for is the "Initialize ecore diagram" option in the dropdown menu by rightclicking on the ecore-file itself.